# Reordering of array elements

Tags: algorithm

Given an array

```
[a1 a2 a3 ... an b1 b2 b3 ... bn c1 c2 c3 ...cn]
```

without using extra memory how do you reorder into an array

```
[a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2 a3 b3 c3 ... an bn cn]
```

Comment: a1 can be some element in the array...not necessary in increasing order.

Comment: I think it's misleading to call this "merging". Merging implies taking two smaller arrays and producing a composite array. I'd call this "reordering", personally. By extra memory, do you mean no additional memory at all, absolutely? Or do you mean no extra memory as "n" increases?

Comment: I gather you mean by only using a constant amount of extra memory. It will be pretty hard to do this without at least 1 temp variable :)

Comment: @Larry: at least for a square matrix, you can use the XOR swap trick and avoid a temporary ;-P.

Answer (score 11):

Your question can also be rephrased as 'How to do an in-place matrix transposition?'. To see why, imagine adding a newline after each subsequence in both of your arrays. This will turn the first array into an NxM matrix, and the second array into an MxN matrix.

Still, it is not trivial for non-square matrices. Please refer to [the Wikipedia page on In-place matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#) for a comprehensive description of the problem and its solutions.

Comment: I checked out the wiki page, but failed to find an algorithm yielding O(1) space. Can you please tell me which one gives O(1) space?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean O(1) memory (or depending on the model O(log n)) rather than *no extra memory*, a linear time in-place algorithm exists.

This paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598 has an algorithm for the case when you have

`a1 ... an b1 ... bn` and want to convert to

`b1 a1 b2 a2 ... bn an`.

The paper also mentions that you can generalize this to other k-way shuffles. In your case, k = 3.

The algorithm in the paper will give the following:

Start with `a1 a2 ... an b1 b2 ... bn c1 c2 ... cn` and convert to

`c1 b1 a1 c2 b2 a2 ... cn bn an`

Another pass through this, and you can easily get `a1 b1 c2 a2 b2 c2 ... an bn cn`.

Now to generalize the algorithm in the paper, we need to pick a prime p, such that k is a primitive root of p^2.

For k = 3, p = 5 will do.

Now to apply the algorithm, first you need to find the largest m < n such 3m+1 is a power of 5.

Note: this will only happen when 3m+1 is an *even* power of 5. Thus you can actually work with powers of 25 when trying to find the m. (5^odd - 1 is not divisible by 3).

Once you find m,

You shuffle the array to be

`[a1 a2 ... am b1 b2 ... bm c1 c2 ... cm] [a(m+1) ... an b(m+1) ... bn c(m+1) ... cn]`

and then use the follow the cycle method(refer the paper) for the first 3m elements, using the powers of 5 (including 1 = 5^0) as the starting points of the different cycles) and do a tail recursion for the rest.

Now to convert
`a1 a2 ... an b1 b2 ... bn c1 c2 ... cn`

to

`[a1 a2 ... am b1 b2 ... bm c1 c2 ... cm] [a(m+1) ... an b(m+1) ... bn c(m+1) ... cn]`

you first do a cyclic shift to get

`a1 a2 ... am [b1 b2  bm a(m+1) .. an] b(m+1) .. bn c1 c2 ... cn`

(the elements in the square brackets are the ones that were shifted)

Then do a cyclic shift to get

`a1 a2 ... am b1 b2  bm a(m+1) .. an [c1 c2 ..cm b(m+1) .. bn ] c(m+1) ... cn`

And then a final shift to

`a1 a2 ... am b1 b2  bm [c1 c2 ..cm a(m+1) .. an ] b(m+1) .. bn  c(m+1) ... cn`

Note that cyclic shift can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space.

So whole algorithm is O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: If someone wants me to elaborate on this further, please let me know.

Comment: I do.  I see that the paper also uses a CycleSort, but it describes breaking the inputs into blocks whose sizes allow calculating in advance which cycles exist. This avoids the extra space or time complexity added when using bits or backtracking as I proposed. But I'm a little confused about what those ideal block sizes are. 5^k-1 gives 3m = 4,24,124,...   Do you round up or down?  It does appear that for m=1 or m=2 there is only one cycle starting at index 1, and for m=8 there are 2 cycles at 1 and 5. What about when k is 3? Should m be 41 or 42?  Do either one have only cycles at 1,5,25?

Comment: @Ashelly: I have elaborated a bit.

Comment: @Moron: so, by this logic, the m's allowed are 8,208,5208,...  What happens when your n is 15 (45 elements)?  After re-ordering, the first 3*8 block can be processed by following the cycles starting at 1 and 5.  But now you are left with a block of 3*7 elements.

Comment: @Ashelly: Yes, I believe so. If you don't like it, you could pick other primes too. I believe picking powers of 7 also works. As to your question, about the remaining, it is a constant number of elements (less than 3*8), which can be done easily in O(1) space. Think of it as the bases cases in an induction step...

Comment: I hit 'add comment ' before I finished, but you answered the question I was on my way to asking.  I guess that works.   However, I can't imagine anyone not familiar with this paper coming up with this answer in an interview.

Comment: @Ashelly: Interviews don't always look for getting the best solutions out of a candidate. For instance, an O(nlogn) solution is possible using divide and conquer (as I mentioned in comments to Arjen's answer). But even that is too much to expect from a candidate in an interview, IMO. Companies like Google are well known for asking hard questions and I guess they have very high standards and perhaps the O(nlogn) time algorithm would be _expected_.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate each item's target position based on its index.

```
groupSize = N/3
group = i/groupSize
rank = i - group * groupSize
dest = rank * 3 + group
```

You can use this calculation with a cycle sort to put each element in its proper place in linear time.  The only issue is tracking which items are already in place.  All you need for that is N bits.  With certain types of data, you can "steal" a bit from the data item itself.    For instance you can use the high bit of ASCII data, or the low byte of word-aligned pointers.

---

Alternately, you can do it without any extra bits at the expense going to polynomial time.   Reverse the calculation, so you can find the original source index of each item in the final array.

```
source = i % groupSize + groupSize * (i/groupSize) ;  //integer division
```

Now walk forward through the array, swapping every item with the one from the source.  The trick is that any time the source index is less than the current position (meaning it has already been swapped out), you need to follow the trail until you find its current location

```
getSource(i):
   s = i % groupSize + groupSize * (i/groupSize)
   while (s<i)
      s = s % groupSize + groupSize * (s/groupSize)
   return s

shuffle:
for i in (0..N-1) 
   swap(a[i],a[getSource(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for certain - just take cards ace, 2, ... 5 in 3 suits and put them in order.

First you take out the a2 card and put it aside.
Then you move the b1 to the a2 position and shift all the cards up

Then you put back the a2 card and put in the shifted out position.

Then you take out the a3 card and puti taside
Move the c1 to the a3 position and shift all the cards up.

Then put back the a3 card in the emptied position.

repeat until done.

The actual calculation of the indices is tricky but I believe a previous poster has done this.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, especially the idea of filling in from the bottom.  But once you start shifting items it becomes awfully tricky, if not impossible, to keep track of where they came from unless you use extra storage.   See my answer for a way to overcome that problem by swapping instead of shifting.